# Formula to determine error code based on binary text output

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to translate some error codes using 22 different formulas and concatenating them afterward to report all errors.

Here is an example of the error code (it is 22 `1's` and `0's`):

`0000000000000000001000`

`0000000000001000000000`

`0000100000001000000010`

Each `1` represents a different error.

Here is one example of the formula I am using:

`=IF(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(D61,1))>=1, " ERROR 1","")`

I have 22 of these formulas and the only differences in any of them are the result and which character it looks for.

---

**My issue is a code with multiple different errors (i.e. more than one `1` is present in the code) will show every error code after the first occurrence of a `1`**. So in the third error code example I listed above, my formula shows every error code after that first `1`. Also, it may not matter but I am using this to combine the resulting errors into 1 column:

`=CONCATENATE(F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2,M2,N2,O2,P2,Q2,R2,S2,T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,Z2,AA2)`

I am trying to get my formula to show *just* the corresponding errors that go with the `1's`, **not** everything after it. I hope this makes sense as it's kind of hard to explain.

If it helps at all the data is being extracted from text files that come in daily and I had to format the cells as **"Text"** in order for them to show the `0's` before the `1's`.

Thanks!

---- EDIT FOR ANYONE CURIOUS ----

This formula ended up working, I placed it in column D, the 22 character code is in column E.

```
=IF(MID(E2,1,1) > "0","ERROR 1 ","") & IF(MID(E2,2,1) > "0","ERROR 2 ","") & IF(MID(E2,3,1) > "0","ERROR 3 ","") & IF(MID(E2,4,1) > "0","ERROR 4 ","") & IF(MID(E2,5,1) > "0","ERROR 5 ","") & IF(MID(E2,6,1) > "0","ERROR 6 ","") & IF(MID(E2,7,1) > "0","ERROR 7 ","") & IF(MID(E2,7,1) > "0","ERROR 7 ","") & IF(MID(E2,8,1) > "0","ERROR 8 ","") & IF(MID(E2,9,1) > "0","ERROR 9 ","") & IF(MID(E2,10,1) > "0","ERROR 10 ","") & IF(MID(E2,11,1) > "0","ERROR 11 ","") & IF(MID(E2,12,1) > "0","ERROR 12 ","") & IF(MID(E2,13,1) > "0","ERROR 13 ","") & IF(MID(E2,14,1) > "0","ERROR 14 ","") & IF(MID(E2,15,1) > "0","ERROR 15 ","") & IF(MID(E2,16,1) > "0","ERROR 16 ","") & IF(MID(E2,17,1) > "0","ERROR 17 ","") & IF(MID(E2,18,1) > "0","ERROR 18 ","") & IF(MID(E2,19,1) > "0","ERROR 19 ","") & IF(MID(E2,20,1) > "0","ERROR 20 ","") & IF(MID(E2,21,1) > "0","ERROR 21 ","") & IF(MID(E2,22,1) > "0","ERROR 22 ","")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a typical 22 bit value in cell **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(MID($A$1,ROWS($1:1),1)="1","Error # "&ROWS($1:1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

To improve the results *(remove the ugly empties)*, in **C1** enter the **array formula**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$22,SMALL((IF(LEN($B$1:$B$22),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($B$1:$B$22))))),ROW(A1)),1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

**EDIT#1:**

Put the following User Defined Function *UDF()* in a standard module:

```
Public Function ErrorLister(s As String)
    Dim arr(1 To 22) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 1 To 22
        arr(i) = ""
    Next i

    j = 1
    For i = 1 To 22
        If Mid(s, i, 1) = "1" Then
            arr(j) = "Error " & i
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ErrorLister = arr
End Function
```

Then select **B1** through **W1**, click in the Formula Bar, and enter the **array formula**:

```
=ErrorLister(A1)
```

then copy **B1** through **W1** downwards:

[image]

Comment: This answer looks promising, the only issue I see is that I have hundreds of these errors in column D. Columns A-C are filled with other MISC data that needs to go with the corresponding errors. Here is an example of some of the errors in Column D.

0000000010000000001000
0000100000010000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000
0000000000000000001000

I need the errors to show in C.

Comment: Currently, It is working but it only shows the first error. If there are multiple it will not show all of them. Columns F thru AA are filled with variations of this formula =IF(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(D2,1))=1, " Error #1,","") and the errors are coded as 1 thru 22. They are then combined in column E using this =CONCATENATE(F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2,M2,N2,O2,P2,Q2,R2,S2,T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,Z2,AA2)

My issue is only the first error shows and I can't get it to show multiples, could this because the column is formatted as Text?

Comment: @Ziggus  In my example, the errors for cell **A1** were listed *downwards* ................would it be better if the errors were listed across...............so all the errors associated with **A1** would be in a single row???

Comment: I do think that might resolve the issue, putting from in the row from Column F-AA and then translating in E seems to be the best route, I am having issues putting this into action though. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ziggus  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Ziggus  You must leave 22 empty cells to the right of the binary data to hold the possible errors, even if the binary data is in column **D**

Comment: I put the function into the module. I moved the error code column to E and all of the columns to the right of it are empty. I put the function into column D and it still only shows the first error. This is what is in D2 =ErrorLister(E2) and This is what is in E2 0000000010000000001000. In theory it should result in D2 showing this : Error 9 Error 19. But it only shows Error 9. Thanks again for all the help with this! :)

Comment: Update for anyone curious, I got it to work using this formula:

Comment: @Ziggus  Good Job!

Answer (score 3):

put this in F2 and copy/drag over:

```
=IF(--MID($D2,column(A:A),1)=1," ERROR " & COLUMN(A:A),"")
```

[image]

---

If you have Office 365 Excel, you can combine them all into one Array formula that will test each part and return the concatenated values:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(--MID($D2,ROW($1:$22),1) = 1, "ERROR " & ROW($1:$22),""))
```

This one being an array formula needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]